# Django user with custom data in multiple apps

Tags: django, django-models

Customer User models was great but if you want to build a project combining multiple apps, each app can assume it's going to have the user model as part of it's models.  My plan is to revert to the standard django User and have a profile in each app.

eg.

app1.models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Class App1User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOne(User)
    special = models.CharField( some field that relates to the user in this app)
```

app2.models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Class App2User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOne(User)
    another = models.CharField( some field that relates to the user in this app)
```

etc.

Then add code to go and get the relevant profile data when needed, maybe adding some middleware or template context processors.  Before I go down this route I wanted to check this is the most Djangoeque solution?

Answer (score 0):

Imho yes, you doing it in the right way.

And you don't need any middleware or context processors to get relevant data for the user.  `OneToOne` field is easily accessible as the attribute of the `user` instance:

```
{{ user.app1user.special }}
{{ user.app2user.another }}
```